# Can jQuery create an element by a selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Normally I would create an element in jQuery like this `$('<div id="errors" class="red"></div>')`

Can I create an element given a selector using something like `$.create("div#errors.red")`? Where that would return a jQuery object representing a `div` with the id of `errors` and the class of `red`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you mean is Zen Coding like DOM creation. You can find the syntax of zen coding on the [zen coding google project page](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/).

Usage would be:

### 1. [download and add the zen-0.1.a.js file](http://code.google.com/p/fluentzen/downloads/list) and add it to your homepage

### 2. add this function to your project

```
var zen = function(input) {
  return jQuery(zen_coding.expandAbbreviation(input, 'html', 'xhtml'));
};
```

### 3. create jQuery dom with:

```
var dom = zen('div#id.class');
$('body').append(dom);
```

Answer (score 3):

### A Plugin

Below is a plugin I wrote that allows you to create an element, simply adorn it with attributes, and append it to the DOM. Here's an example use of `.adorn()` with what you wanted to do:

```
$("<div>").adorn("#errors",".red",">body");
```

The above creates a `div`, slaps on an `ID` and a `Class` and appends it all to the `body`. Note that you can add the `appendTo` syntax in any order, so this will work too:

```
$("<div>").adorn(">body","#errors",".red");
```

### **[Simple example page created with adorn.](http://jsfiddle.net/TathN/)**

As opposed to using one continuos string, I found it easier to pass each class, id, value, etc. in as an argument, since that clearly delineates them.

### Syntax:

- `.blah`  - adds class `blah`
- `#blah`  - sets id to `blah`
- `>blah`  - appends this to `blah`
- `h:blah` - sets innerHTML to `blah`
- `v:blah` - sets value to `blah`
- There's 9 options currently
- ... you can easily add new functionality.

*Note that when used, the colon, can be any single character, it doesn't have to be a colon, so `h-blah` would also work.*

### Other Uses:

The nice thing about this plugin is that it cannot only be used to adorn newly created elements, but it can also be used to adorn existing elements. For example to add 3 classes and set the HTML for all divs on a page:

```
$("div").adorn(".one",".two",".three","h:blah");
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xQ9z6/)**

Finally, if you accidentally pass in the wrong label. **[An error class is added to the element](http://jsfiddle.net/rwMm6/)** to ease debugging, but things will not break.

### How it Works:

The heart of this plugin is making use of the automatically available **[arguments array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)**  to hold all the passed in options. The options are parsed using a **[switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)** and the **[substring method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)**.

### The plugin:

```
(function( $ ){
    jQuery.fn.adorn = function () {
          // Get the arguments array for use in the closure
        var $arguments = arguments;
          // Maintain chainability
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $.each($arguments, function(index, value) {
                  // These are just the options that quickly came
                  //   to mind, you can easily add more.
                  // Which option is used depends on the first
                  //   character of the argument passed in. The 2nd
                  //   char is sometimes used and sometimes ignored.
                switch (value.substring(0,1)) {
                    case "#":
                        $this.attr("id",value.substring(1));
                    break;
                    case ".":
                        $this.addClass(value.substring(1));
                    break;
                    case ">":
                        $this.appendTo(value.substring(1));
                    break;                          
                    case "a":
                        $this.attr("alt", value.substring(2));
                    break;
                    case "h":
                        $this.html(value.substring(2));
                    break;
                    case "i":
                        $this.attr("title", value.substring(2));
                    break;
                    case "s":
                        $this.attr("src", value.substring(2));
                    break;
                    case "t":
                        $this.attr("type", value.substring(2));
                    break;
                    case "v":
                        $this.attr("value", value.substring(2));
                    break;
                    default:
                          // if the wrong key was entered, create
                          // an error class.
                        $this.addClass("improper-adorn-label");
                }
            });
        });
    };
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do that, the closer thing i know is that you can do

```
var newdiv = $.DIV({ className: "red", id: "errors"});
```

the div is created and you can append events and stuff directly to the variable

using this plugin http://mg.to/2006/02/27/easy-dom-creation-for-jquery-and-prototype

Answer (score -2):

You can try this method:

```
$("<div id="errors" class="red"></div>").appendTo("body");
```