# jquery create new child, or update existing child

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

if I have this html

```
<div>
  <p>1</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
</div>
```

and this jquery

```
$('div').each(function () {
    $(this).find('p').eq(1).html('test');
});
```

i get this

```
<div>
  <p>1</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>test</p>
</div>
```

what jquery should I use to get this instead?

```
<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>test</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>test</p>
</div>
```

there is no match for `eq(1)` on the first div so it just skips it. how can I add a child if none exists or update it if one does exist, without having to split the jquery into several statements?

Comment: What do you mean by `without having to split the jquery into several statements`? Are `if` statements forbidden?

Comment: it is my understanding that 1 line of code is generally better than 5 lines of code if it does the same thing and is easily understandable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery "get or create element" convenience method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404575/jquery-get-or-create-element-convenience-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `<div>` elements contain at most two paragraphs, you can do:

```
$("div").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find("p").add($("<p>")).eq(1).html("test").appendTo($this);
});
```

If there are more than two paragraphs, things get more complicated and you'll have to use [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) instead of [appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) to add the new element to the DOM:

```
$("div").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find("p").add($("<p>")).eq(1).html("test")
         .insertAfter($this.find("p").eq(0));
});
```

You can see the results in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gzX2n/).

Comment: May i ask why you change $(this) to $this?

Comment: @Joey, to spare a call to `$()`, so the code will be slightly faster. This practice is usually usually referred to as *caching $(this)*.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way i found is this lets see someone else come with smaller solution

```
<div>
  <p>1</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
</div>

$('div').each(function () {
    var elm= $(this).find('p').eq(1);
    if(elm.length==0)
    {
        $(this).find('p').after('test');
    }
    else
    {
        elm.html('test')
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/geBXF/

Comment: yup, that's basically what i came up with too. i was hoping somebody a little more familiar with jquery than i am would know a more concise syntax

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of keeping a separation of concerns, here's an jQuery function that will either locate an existing element or create a new element.

#### So just include this jQuery anywhere:

```js
$.fn.upsert = function(selector, htmlString) {
  // upsert - find or create new element
  // find based on css selector     https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
  // create based on jQuery()       http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2
  var $el = $(this).find(".message");
  if ($el.length == 0) {
    // didn't exist, create and add to caller
    $el = $("<span class='message'></span>");
    $(this).append($el);
  }

  return $el;
};
```

#### Then you could use like this:

```js
$("input[name='choice']").click(function(){
  var $el = $(this).closest("form").upsert(".message", "<span class='message'></span>");
  // guaranteed to have element - update if we want
  $el.html("You've chosen "+this.value)
})
```

Ideally, it would be nice to simply pass in a selector and have jQuery create an element that matches that selector automatically, but it doesn't seem like there's a light weight vehicle for [creating an element](http://api.jquery.com/?s=createElement()) based off the CSS Selector syntax (based on [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3518650/1366033) & [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10586678/1366033)).

Some further enhancements might provide more fine tuned control for [DOM insertion](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/) instead of just always using [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

#### [Demo in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/z13swd33/) |  Demo in Stack Snippets:

```js
$.fn.upsert = function(selector, htmlString) {
  // upsert - find or create new element
  // find based on css selector    https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
  // create based on jQuery()       http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2
  var $el = $(this).find(".message");
  if ($el.length == 0) {
    // didn't exist, create and add to caller
    $el = $("<span class='message'></span>");
    $(this).append($el);
  }

  return $el;
}; 

$("input[name='choice']").click(function(){
  var $el = $(this).closest("form").upsert(".message", "<span class='message'></span>");
  // guaranteed to have element - update if we want
  $el.html("You've chosen "+this.value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="ca" name="choice" value="A" /><label for='ca'>A</label>
    <input type="radio" id="cb" name="choice" value="B" /><label for='cb'>B</label>
    <input type="radio" id="cc" name="choice" value="C" /><label for='cc'>C</label>
  </div>
</form>
```